# How can I get make to interleave including files and rebuilding the included files in the order they are specified in the file?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile `foo`:

```
all: output

bar:
        echo 'ALL = there' > "$@"

-include bar

MORE := $(ALL)

baz: foo bar
        echo MORE=$(MORE)
        echo 'SOME = there' > "$@"

-include baz

output: baz
        echo SOME=$(SOME)
```

When I run `rm -f bar baz; make -f foo`, I get

```
echo 'ALL = there' > "bar"
echo MORE=
MORE=
echo 'SOME = there' > "baz"
echo SOME=there
SOME=there
```

I expect to get

```
echo 'ALL = there' > "bar"
echo MORE=there
MORE=there
echo 'SOME = there' > "baz"
echo SOME=there
SOME=there
```

How do I fix this?  That is, how to I make it so that `bar` has been included, after being regenerated, when executing the target to generate `baz`?

Running `make -v` gives

```
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-pc-cygwin
Copyright (C) 1988-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Make always reads the entire makefile, then tries to build all the makefiles it found, then (if any were remade) restarts.  It will do this recursively until no makefiles are rebuilt, though.  You cannot change this algorithm.  See @Beta's answer: that's the right (only, unless you want to use recursive makefiles) to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the "-include baz" inside bar:

```
bar:
    @echo making $@
    @echo 'ALL = there' > "$@"
    @echo "-include baz" >> $@
```